# Pop Up Div Manipulated Using JavaScript and JQuery is Glitchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

Good day everyone.

I'm building a simple Joomla module that populates a hidden div, using jquery ajax, on hover over each item displayed per row, after populating the div is displayed, and when the cursor is out of the item and out of that item and out of any other item, the the displayed div should disappear. Problem is that it disappears sometimes, and it remains at other times.

I found out that 
- it disappears when you mouse out from parent item div
- it appears when you mouse out children of item div.

I'd really appreciate a quick help - thanks!

Hears the page I'm working on

http://www.cooltv.cool/schedule

The module on top, titled 'Programs', is the glitchy one.

Here's my JavaScript code - I'm using jQuery library.

```
wpshProgramItem = jQuery('.wps_highlight .wpsh_program_item');
wpshProgramTooltip = jQuery('.wps_highlight .wpsh_program_tooltip');

popUpHandler: function () {
    wpshProgramItem.bind("mouseover", function (e) {
        console.log("ProgramItem YES mouseover");

        curItem = jQuery(this);

        var
        url = "index.php?option=com_wetvprogramscheduler&task=getSynopsis",
        urlData = {
            pid: curItem.attr('programid')
        };

        SynopsisPopUp.programItemAjax(url, urlData);
    }).bind("mouseout", function () {
        wpshProgramTooltip.hide();
        console.log("ProgramItem mouseout");
    }).bind("mouseleave", function () {
        wpshProgramTooltip.hide();
    });

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is because there is a `div` under "Programs" with the class `wpsh_program_item` which you are calling in your script. Check Firebug or your browser inspector and you will see what I mean

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - it is the div with the class wpsh_program_item's mouseover and mouseout events that displays the div with the class wpsh_program_tooltip. I have checked the inspector over and over before and after your comment and still can't find anything wrong. The logged events for div.wpsh_program_item seems fine, I still don't see why div.wpsh_program_tooltip would display if the last logged event for div.wpsh_program_item is a mouseout event.